# Which SDK Version Does Appengine Use in Production

Tags: google-app-engine

If I have the (let's say) 1.5.3 version of the AppEngine Python SDK that I use to develop my apps, and the most current SDK version is 1.8.3, what version will be used in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dashboard/console tells you. The current version in production is 1.8.6 .  The production runtime sometimes is updated before the SDK is released.

Comment: Will production always use the most recent version?

Comment: Production uses whatever is put into production by google.  You really have no control (especially with python).  Not sure what parts of the SDK are deployed with java though.  Mayebe someone else can comment on that ?

Comment: They usually have a pre-release SDK, then latest production is updated, then the prod SDK is released.

Comment: So regardless of the SDK that I am using on my development server, production will always use the latest?

Comment: Yep, you have no control.

Comment: Great, thanks! So if I test my app with a really old SDK version (that was current at the time), it is possible that later releases might break functionality or side-effects (if it's a really big change)?

Answer (score 2):

The SDK has several components. You'll get the latest version of App Engine APIs, but for "versioned" third party components (like Django, numpy, etc.), if you declare a specific version in `app.yaml`, you'll get that version, and we'll provide advance warning if or when older versions go away.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27